# Optimizing recursive query in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, recursive-query

I'm having a issue with a recursive query in Oracle.

Let say I've a table "NAMES" with structure:

| PROPERTY | NAME | REFERENCE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Mike | 1 |
| 1 | John | 4 |
| 1 | James | 4 |
| 1 | Robert | 4 |
| 4 | Michael | 5 |
| 5 | David | 6 |
| 6 | Mark | NULL |

and simple recursive query:

```
WITH rec as
(
 SELECT N_1.PROPERTY, N_1.NAME, N_1.REFERENCE 
 FROM NAMES N_1
 WHERE PROPERTY = 0
 UNION ALL
 SELECT N_2.PROPERTY, N_2.NAME, N_2.REFERENCE  
 FROM NAMES N_2
 JOIN rec r ON T_2.PROPERTY = r.REFERENCE
)
SELECT NAME FROM rec;
```

witch gives:

| NAME |
| --- |
| Mike |
| James |
| John |
| Robert |
| Michael |
| Michael |
| Michael |
| David |
| David |
| David |
| Mark |
| Mark |
| Mark |

So, everything works correctly. But the issue is: for Mike - found 3 records: James, John, Robert (it is Ok) - then for each of them found Michael (3 times, again Ok) - but then for each Michael's appearance found it's own David (but that is the same Davids, for the same Michaels!) - and then for each David found it's own Mark (for the same Marks - the same Davids).

My goal is just to find full hierarchy down from Mike i.e. find all elements that can be reached from Mike walking by REFERENCE = PROPERTY. So, my desirable result set looks like:

| NAME |
| --- |
| Mike |
| James |
| John |
| Robert |
| Michael |
| David |
| Mark |

I know that I can reach my goal by adding 'DISTINCT':

```
...
SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM rec;
```

But the point is that extra records (excessive Davids and Marks ) will be found anyway - but will be just discarded from result. That is bad for me because my real table is much more complex than example and extra searches take a looooot of time.
So, is there way to say to database - 'if you find Michael 3 times - do not search his reference 3 times - search just once'.

Thanks in advance:)

P.S. First what i thought about was to do something like:

```
WITH rec as
(
...
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DISTINCT N_2.PROPERTY, N_2.NAME, N_2.REFERENCE  
 FROM NAMES N_2
 JOIN rec r ON T_2.PROPERTY = r.REFERENCE
)
SELECT NAME FROM rec;
```

But Oracle do not like it.

Answer (score 0):

One method may be to find the `DISTINCT` pairs of `property` and `reference` and then generate the hierarchy and `JOIN` back to the `NAMES` table to get the names:

```sql
WITH relationships (property, reference) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT property, reference
  FROM   names
),
hierarchy (property) AS (
  SELECT property
  FROM   relationships
  START WITH property = 0
  CONNECT BY PRIOR reference = property
)
SELECT n.name
FROM   hierarchy h
       INNER JOIN names n
       ON (h.property = n.property)
```

or

```sql
WITH relationships (property, reference) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT property, reference
  FROM   names
),
hierarchy (property, reference) AS (
  SELECT property, reference
  FROM   relationships
  WHERE  property = 0
UNION ALL
  SELECT r.property, r.reference
  FROM   hierarchy h
         INNER JOIN relationships r
         ON h.reference = r.property
)
SELECT n.name
FROM   hierarchy h
       INNER JOIN names n
       ON (h.property = n.property)
```

Which output:

| NAME |
| --- |
| Mike |
| John |
| James |
| Robert |
| Michael |
| David |
| Mark |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aR9N1M_7)